# Sort lists of float-like strings

Tags: python

I need to sort to the following list:

```
b = ['0.10', '0.1', '0.11', '0.12', '0.2', '0.3']
```

… so that the output will be:

```
['0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.10', '0.11', '0.12']
```

They look like `float` values, but that's not the order I want - they need to be treated as if they are version numbers - i.e. 0.1 is not 0.10 (the first is zero dot one, the second is zero dot ten). When I use `float` as a key, I get a different order:

```
>>>b.sort(key=float)
>>>b 
['0.10', '0.1', '0.11', '0.12', '0.2', '0.3']
```

I also want to sort the following list:

```
['3.0.1', '3.0.10', '3.0.11', '3.0.12', '3.0.2', '3.0.3', 
 '3.0.4', '3.0.5', '3.0.6', '3.0.7', '3.0.8', '3.0.9', 
 '3.1.1', '3.1.10', '3.1.11', '3.1.12', '3.1.2', '3.1.3', 
 '3.1.4', '3.1.5', '3.1.6', '3.1.7', '3.1.8', '3.1.9']
```

In this order:

```
['3.0.1', '3.0.2', '3.0.3', '3.0.4', '3.0.5', '3.0.6',
 '3.0.7', '3.0.8', '3.0.9', '3.0.10', '3.0.11', '3.0.12',
 '3.1.1', '3.1.2', '3.1.3', '3.1.4', '3.1.5', '3.1.6',
 '3.1.7', '3.1.8', '3.1.9', '3.1.10', '3.1.11', '3.1.12']
```

Comment: The last time I checked, `0.1` and `0.10` were equal.

Comment: Your input and output don't match. Strings vs. float values, *and* the output presents `0.1` as `0.10`, which is not possible. Give us your *real* values please.

Comment: The [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) strikes again...

Comment: @thefourtheye: Maybe this is actually a sophisticated question, and he expects us to assume he understands the rounding issues with floats, so his `0.10` and `0.1` are not necessarily equal. But that still doesn't explain how `0.3` is less than either one of them, so… maybe it's not such a sophisticated question. :)

Comment: @abarnert Ah, your answer makes sense, upvoted it :) Still, the question is not clear, so CVed it.

Comment: @thefourtheye: There is a reasonable question here, the OP just hasn't expressed himself well enough without reading the comments and a bit of mind-reading. I can edit this into something worth keeping, but I'm not sure whether that too radically changes it to be acceptable. Want to check it over and see what you think?

Comment: @abarnert I believe, your example really makes this question worth keeping :-) Lifting the CV.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: I've approved your further edit, but if it goes through I'll need to edit my answer as well. (Probably a good thing.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've tried to sort a list of version strings as float values. The floating point number `0.3` is greater than `0.10`, not less; that's obviously not what you want.

The key here is that version strings (and IP addresses and similar things) are dot-separated integers, not floating-point numbers, even when they only have 2 components and look like they are.* You want to pull out those integers and sort them as a sequence of numbers.

To do that, just split the string on `.`, convert the components to integers, and the normal lexicographical-sorting rules on sequences will take care of the rest:

```
b.sort(key=lambda vers: [int(component) for component in vers.split('.')])
```

The only other reasonable thing I can see that would fit your desired output is a more general version of the same idea, called "natural sort": it treats every run of digits as an integer, but every other character as a character. (For example, that can be used to make `"picture 9.jpg"` come before `"picture 10.jpg"`, as it would in OS X's Finder.) But this takes a bit more code, so I'm going with the more specific, simpler guess.

---

<sub>* There are some projects that actually do use floating-point numbers for versions… but of course they never go to version 3.10, because that would be smaller than 3.9. Instead, they'll use, e.g., 3.99, then 3.999, and so on. Obviously for version numbers that really are floats, you want to use `float` as the key…</sub>

Comment: @NileshG: Then edit your question so this is what you're actually asking. That will probably get rid of some of your downvotes and/or get you some upvotes, and it'll make the question useful to other people with the same problem who find it via search.